# Create a Document Library with column values programmatically with Javascript

Tags: 2010, javascript

I need to create a Document Library and assign it columns with Javascript.

I've been searching around and I found the SP.ListCreationInformation documentation.  Here is my code so far:

```
function createDocLibrary() {
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();

    var lci = new SP.ListCreationInformation ();
    lci.set_title('My Custom Title');
    lci.set_templateType(101); 

    this.oList = web.get_lists().add(lci);
    ctx.load(oList);
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.newPBDLSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.newPBDLFail));

}
function newPBDLSuccess() {
    alert('success');    
}
function newPBFail() {
    alert('fail');
}
```

I can create the document library (thanks @Dylan Cristy for catching my mistake - I updated the code on this post), but am stuck on how to create the libraries columns with javascript.

Also, I'm using ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(createDocLibrary, "sp.js"); to ensure sp.js is loaded first.

Does anyone have a working example of creating a Document Library (or list) and setting its columns with javascript?

Comment: Looks like you want to use `ListCreationInformation` (which you mention above your code block, and link to), but in your code you apparently are using `ListItemCreationInformation`.  Reference here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitemcreationinformation(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without being able to provide you with specific code examples, I'd say that now that you've created your Document Library, and have a reference to it as `this.oList`, you can use the [`SP.List.fields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee556713%28v=office.14%29.aspx) property to get the field collection for the list, and use the [`SP.FieldCollection.add()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658526%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method to add fields to the list.  Since `add` takes an `SP.Field` object as an argument, you may need to get your reference to the field object by pulling it out of the web's field collection, using [`SP.FieldCollection.getByInternalNameOrTitle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee658548%28v=office.14%29.aspx) method.